# Mediawiki Database Error 1205

Tags: mysql, mediawiki, database-deadlocks

I just installed a fresh copy of mediawiki on http://konton.us/wiki

I was all happy playing around with my wiki, filling up the place with information and suddently, when I created an article by the name of Gameplay_Mechanics, it all went dead.

http://konton.us/wiki/Gameplay_Mechanics

I got this error:

A database query syntax error has occurred. This may indicate a bug in the software. The last attempted database query was:
(SQL query hidden)
from within function "". Database returned error "1205: Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction (internal-db.s76387.gridserver.com)".

I was able to fix it by 'emptying' the article and then saving it - only to repopulate it again but...it happened less than 1 day later...again, so I'm kind of wondering what is the ACTUAL ROOT CAUSE of this ridiculous error.

All help is appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try deleting the page, then recreating it with a slightly different name. It might just be a weird fluke thing having to do with that page specifically.

Comment: Yeah, it's weird...for example:

Let's say yesterday I had...200 lines of text when the error first popped up. After 'emptying' the article and then re-populating it, I went all the way to 600 lines of code. Now that today I wanted to continue writing, the article only got to the first 200 lines...as if I had never written the next 400. What's up with that?

I am beginning to suspect there is something 'funny' about the code in the 200 char 'limit' so to speak that makes the code break and end up giving that 1205 error?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using MySQL 5.1.26rc for a specific reason? Maybe upgrade to 5.1.49?

http://konton.us/wiki/Special:Version

Comment: It's the version provided by my webhost. Why, is it known as particularly buggy?

Comment: Dunno, but if it's only a release candidate maybe it's buggy. You could ask your host.

Answer (score 0):

This looks more like your database server being too busy. This error is often a sign of deadlocked transactions, although I'm not sure MediaWiki even uses transactions.

Are there many users visiting your site? Perhaps you're sharing your hosting with another high-traffic site?

Comment: Nope, currently it's just me visiting the site. I even had 'blocked' anonymous viewers and all that in my localsetting.php file. I commented that part so you guys could go and have a look. I'm using a grid-server hosting package from mediatemple so maybe that could be part of the reason. I wonder though, I've...had many other database-requiring apps before and have literally...'choked' the system with looping statements and queries and nothing like this ever happened. I'm surprised something like a newborn,  baby wiki could make the server time out.

Comment: Oh, and by the way, yes, it is most likely a deadlocked transaction. If it though, how do we go about fixing it?

Comment: how about this?
http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:$wgAntiLockFlags

How would I set that var? I'm unfamiliar with 'bitfields' - I have no idea what they are but, in the defaultsettings.php file it has:

$wgAntiLockFlags = 0;

So I suppose 0 = option 1, 1 = option 2 and so forth?

Should I then go for option #3 = number 2?

Comment: $wgAntiLockFlags = ALF_NO_LINK_LOCK | ALF_NO_BLOCK_LOCK was said to fix this issue in some other forum but i dont see it working

Comment: Mediawiki without any caching uses a lot of resources and is pretty slow, even just for a small number of users.